# Upload image as np array to FIrebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to the Firebase storage.
I have no problems doing that when uploading a local image, with:

```
import pyrebase
db_credentials = "local_file.json"
        firebase_config = {
            'apiKey': "...",
            'authDomain': "...",
            'databaseURL': "...",
            'projectId': "...",
            'storageBucket': "...",
            'messagingSenderId': "...",
            'appId': "...",
            'measurementId': "...",
            'serviceAccount': db_credentials
        }
firebase_storage = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_config)
storage = firebase_storage.storage()
storage.child('remote_path').put('local_path.png')
```

However, in my case the image is a frame from a remote camera, retrieved by using OpenCV, so that I have it as a np.array. I tried using it as in the previous example, but it doesn't work.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(remote_camera_address)
ret, frame = cap.read() -> frame is a np array
storage.child('remote_path').put(frame)
```

This is returning the error:

```
raise ValueError('total bytes could not be determined. Please '
ValueError: total bytes could not be determined. Please pass an explicit size.
```

Clearly, I could save the np array to a local image, upload that image and delete it afterwards, but I was wondering if I could do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: I'm not sure what SDK you're using, but the error message seems the same as here (which shows how to pass he size): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210646/uploading-image-file-to-google-bucket-in-python

Comment: Added a few more info now. The solution you linked seems to be using a different library than what I'm doing now, I'll take a look at it

Comment: Ah, you're using Pyrebase. That abstracts the call in the answer I linked in its [`put` implementation](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/7a652e6bd9d148da5ff6dbe7548c6d5d0dfa1109/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L384-L407). You might want to use the underlying bucket yourself directly, or you could consider filing a feature request for Pyrebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210646/uploading-image-file-to-google-bucket-in-python) it seems that you can pass a `chunk_size` parameter to get rid of this problem:

```
blob = self.bucket.blob(filename, chunk_size=262144) # 256KB
blob.upload_from_file(image)
```

Since you are using Pyrebase, the call to `upload_from_file` is actually wrapped in its [`put` implementation](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/7a652e6bd9d148da5ff6dbe7548c6d5d0dfa1109/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L384-L407) that you are calling, so you can either drop Pyrebase for this operation and make the calls on the bucket directly, or you can file a feature request for Pyrebase to add support for this feature.